# How to append to definition of a macro which has arguments?

Tags: macros, expansion

I’ve been using `\let\oldsomething\something\renewcommand*something{\oldsomething ...}` in a couple places, but it’s tedious and I guess prone to errors if I were to try to redefine again with the same auxiliary macro.

After learning about `\g@addto@macro` I was happy for a while. Then arose the need to append to a command which has arguments:

```
\newcommand*{\hello}[1]{Hello #1}
\g@addto@macro{\hello}{!}
\show\hello
```

That sequence prints:

```
> \hello=macro:
Hello !.
```

So, the argument seems to disappear. The result I was attempting is:

```
> \hello=macro:
->Hello #1!.
```

Is there some easy way to change the middle line to obtain this, or is it back to the old way for macros with arguments?

Comment: Package `etoolbox`'s `\patchcmd` is probably what you're looking for…

Comment: And `xpatch` if the command is defined with optional arguments or with `\DeclareDocumentCommand`